# When should I open/close a connection to the database ? (MariaDB / node.js)

Tags: mysql, node.js, mariadb

I am using https://github.com/mscdex/node-mariasql

I've got these stages in the process of running a query on the DB :

```
var Client = require('mariasql');
var client = new Client();
client.connect(...);
client.query(...);
client.end();
```

When should I run these ?

Run the whole thing (except the require of course) on every query ?
Keep one instance of client and keep it open all the time, and just run .query for every query ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just need to `query()` for every query. Although if you want/need query concurrency > 1 then you should use a generic pooling module (there are at least a few on npm) to create a pool of mariasql connections instead.